# My yeast doesn't bubble but kinda works?

Tags: yeast

I only have regular access to 2 yeast products here - active dry yeast from company #1 and active dry yeast from company #2.

I'm proofing them by mixing 6g of yeast + 1tsp of sugar + 325ml of room temperature water but unlike I've seen in youtube videos, neither of them makes any bubbles after 10 mins of waiting.. the surface of the liquid is completely still.

They still seem to rise the dough though, my pizza dough balls grow around 4x their size after a few hours at room temperature or a day in the fridge.

So is my yeast dead or alive? Maybe its just shy?

Comment: If the dough rises as stated, the yeast is fine.  Activation is not even really needed in many cases, it just speeds things along and confirms the yeast is OK. The temps that Cynetta gives will likely show you quicker and more vigorous activity.  Personally, I do not even wait to see activity, I just assume the warm water and a pinch of salt with wake them up and go with it when I get the other ingredients ready  If you are doing something with a short rise time it can be more important to make sure of the bubbling first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I whisk together active dry yeast with water at 105 to 115 degrees F (40.5 to 45 degrees C), not room temperature water

If the kneaded dough rises properly (as expected) I believe nothing is wrong and no action is required
Your yeast is alive and fine!